# FileUpload.hasFile returning false inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have been through several links but didn't find anything helpful. I know it has been asked several times here.

Here is my frontend code

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuItemImage"  Width="370px" TabIndex="12" />
     </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>

            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the backend code

```
  if (fuItemImage.HasFile)
  {
    MyFunction.UploadThisFile(anything)
  }
```

When I upload any image and click on the save button it shows false in FileUpload.HasFile. I am stuck and finding no solution for it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `UpdatePanel` and `FileUpload` do not work together. FileUpload needs a full PostBack.If you want async file upload you'll have to use something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
           <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuItemImage"  Width="370px" TabIndex="12" />
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

     </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "Button1" />

            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

add the button id in triggers to upload the file which will do postback